# Problem when deploying new app in tomcat6 server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat6, amazon-web-services

i have written the webservices suing SOAP, and its still under development. When have set of code which are already running the webapps folder of tomcat6. When I make changes in particular file I replaced only that file but stopping the tomcat server and restarting the tomcat server, but I am not able to see any changes in the application, itself reflecting the old functionality itself. I deleted the whole project and deployed a new project with the same folder name, then also I am not able to see the new changes some times, I get an error in the browser which says resources not found. But it works fine when I create a new folder with different name and deploy application in the new created folder. I am not understand, what actually happening. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat caches servlet response in %CATALINA_HOME%/work/Catalina/localhost/myapp.  If you're really desperate you can delete that directory manually.  However, normally setting [reloadable=true in the Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) will make Tomcat automatically reload the Web app.  Also, if you deploy it using the manager app instead of just dropping the WAR, that reloads it automatically.

Comment: I am not able to find %CATALINA_HOME in my ubuntu server, how i do it please explain me since I am novice.

Comment: I have a FTPServer running in the tomcat6/webapps/myfolder/FTPServer.class, before it was running in a different location inside webapps folder, the previuos path was /webapps/WEB-INF/classes/com/m/f/FTPServer, though the file path is changed when I try to that FTPServer still its taking the old path itself. How do I solve this problem

Comment: CATALINA_HOME is a variable either set in your environment or in your tomcat startup script. I don't understand your second question.